# Importing extra API data via importJSON + usage of data from json in formulas

Tags: json, google-sheets-api

I have made a google sheet with support of Tanaike. It is fully functional but I want to change something in the input and also a colum resulted in another format or formula. This are the things where I was stuck. First of all this is my code:

```
function updateStampInSheet(e) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
    var stamp = new Date();
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(stamp);
}
function SAMPLE() {
  const url1 = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/mapping";
  const url2 = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest";
  const [res1, res2] = [url1, url2].map(url => JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()));
  const head = ['id', 'name', 'examine', 'members', 'lowalch', 'highalch', 'limit', 'high', 'low', 'lowTime', 'highTime','icon'];
  const obj1 = res1.reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id] = e, o), {});
  const obj2 = Object.entries(res2.data).reduce((o, [k, v]) => (o[k] = v, o), {});
  const keys = Object.keys(obj1).map(e => Number(e)).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  const values = [head, ...keys.map(k => {
    const o = Object.assign(obj1[k], obj2[k]);
    return head.map(h => o[h] ? (['lowTime', 'highTime'].includes(h) ? Utilities.formatDate(new Date(o[h] * 1000), timeZone, "HH:mm:ss") : o[h]) : "");
  })];
  return values;
}
```

1. The json is updating every second and the datestamp is printed in the sheet. Also when updating there is a column called "lowTime" and "highTime". Is it possible to add 2 extra columns with the following data with the data from now subtracted with "lowTime" or "highTime"? In a sheet is it possible but I couldn't figure out how I could do it in the code. See following picture: https://postimg.cc/GTRJ3FP5
2. The id is known, based on the ID I would like to show a picture then can get found in the following link: for example id=2:https://static.runelite.net/cache/item/icon/2.png. Is it possible to the valuable id in a formula for example =IMAGE("https://static.runelite.net/cache/item/icon/2.png") in an extra column?
   I have explained in the following picture:https://postimg.cc/nCbczdDz
3. I tried to add a third json in the database but it gives all the time an error (an extra column). This is the following: https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/volumes. It gives volumes corresponding to the id.
4. My last question, how can I use data from the json database in a formula (extra column)? For example look picture in the link, I tried some functions but the result didn't work out https://postimg.cc/PCPNBLss.

I hope it is al clear for you all, if not please comment (this is the google spreadheet, I have added the colums: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fFrVLCWyCwDcqSU5-Bpt_C4sHXzLHFA30gk84TaUwOE/edit#gid=0).

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 4 questions. Can I ask you about the detail of them? I saw your sample Spreadsheet. Is that the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your 4 questions.

Comment: Hello Tanaike! Thank you for the reply. I added my desired columns with the values that I want. What I want that this is calculated in the program (every minute) and not is calculated in the sheet by formulas because this resulted in a very slow file. Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your updated sample Spreadsheet, I thought that I might be able to understand your 1st and 2nd questions. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 3rd and 4th questions. I cannot understand your all 4 questions. By this, I cannot answer to your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. The first 2 questions are clear? The third is to add an extra API implemented ```   const url1 = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/mapping";
  const url2 = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest";
  const url3 = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/volumes"; where there is an id corresponsing to a volume. Last question is to make a formula with the data from the API's and put this in an extra column. What language do you speak?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated sample Spreadsheet, I thought that you wanted to add the columns "L" to "S", and I thought that this is the 1st and 2nd questions. So, I thought that I cannot still understand your 3rd and 4th questions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do from `The third is to add an extra API implemented ``` const url1 = "prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/mapping"; const url2 = "prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest"; const url3 = "prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/volumes"; where there is an id corresponsing to a volume. Last question is to make a formula with the data from the API's and put this in an extra column.`.

Comment: Thank you for replying, no this is column "L" to "N". Column "O" to "R" is question 4 and question 3 is column "S". Is it clear now? In the pictures is more info.

Comment: <https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/volumes> shows id and volume. Id is known from other API. I want an extra column that show the corresponding volume to the id based on this API.

Comment: This picture make question 3 more clear: <https://ibb.co/ysDdx7p>

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1st and 2nd questions are the columns "L" to "N". 3rd question is the columns "O" to "R". 4th question is the column "S". Is my understanding correct? And, in your situation, you are required to use the formulas? Because in this case, when the structure of the data and the sheet is changed the formulas cannot be able to be used. I'm worried about this.

Comment: Is right. The formulas are not needed in the sheet. The result of the formula is OK for me. I found that this could be done by this way but I couldn't figure out. <https://postimg.cc/PCPNBLss>.

Comment: For example, in your situation, I think that the custom function cannot be used. Because the image is put to the cell using the formula. In this case, what do you want to do? I cannot understand your goal in this situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Is it possible that this formula can be pasted as string with the correct id?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Is it possible that this formula can be master as string with the correct id? `.

Comment: The link is always the same. The only thing that changes or is variable is the id from the api. U understand?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Is your reply the answer to my question of `For example, in your situation, I think that the custom function cannot be used. Because the image is put to the cell using the formula. In this case, what do you want to do?`? In order to resolve your 4 questions, I think that the custom function cannot be used. Is this situation your expected direction? I'm worried about this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for the reply. If this is not possible ignore last question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your 4 requests, how about the following sample script? Unfortunately, in order to achieve your 4 requests, the custom function cannot be used. So, in this sample script, please run the script with the script editor.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet name. And, please run `sample2` with the script editor. By this, the script is run.

```js
function sample2() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  // Set the value to the cell "A1".
  const stamp = new Date();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(stamp);
  const date = stamp.getTime();

  // Retrieve values from URLs.
  const url1 = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/mapping";
  const url2 = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest";
  const url3 = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/volumes";
  const [res1, res2, res3] = [url1, url2, url3].map(url => JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()));

  // Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  const head = ['id', 'name', 'examine', 'members', 'lowalch', 'highalch', 'limit', 'high', 'low', 'lowTime', 'highTime'];
  const exHead = ["Icon", "Low Time (mins)", "High Time (mins)", "margin", "profit", "tax", "roi", "volume"];
  const obj1 = res1.reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id] = e, o), {});
  const obj2 = Object.entries(res2.data).reduce((o, [k, v]) => (o[k] = v, o), {});
  const obj3 = res3.data;
  const keys = Object.keys(obj1).map(e => Number(e)).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const values = [[...head, ...exHead], ...keys.map(k => {
    const o = Object.assign(obj1[k], obj2[k]);
    const temp = head.map(h => o[h] ? (['lowTime', 'highTime'].includes(h) ? new Date(o[h] * 1000) : o[h]) : "");
    const colO = temp[7] - temp[8];
    const colQ = temp[7] * 0.01;
    const colP = colO - colQ;
    const exTemp = [`=IMAGE("https://static.runelite.net/cache/item/icon/${temp[0]}.png")`, temp[9] ? Math.floor((date - temp[9].getTime()) / 60000) : null, temp[10] ? Math.floor((date - temp[10].getTime()) / 60000) : null, colO, colP, colQ, colP && temp[8].toString() ? colP / temp[8] : 0, obj3[k] || 0];
    return [...temp, ...exTemp];
  })];
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

  // Set number format. These formats are retrieved from your sample Spreadsheet.
  sheet.getRange(3, 10, values.length, 2).setNumberFormat("d-m-yyyy");
  const formats = ['#,##0 "minutes ago"', '#,##0 "minutes ago"', "0", "0", "0", "0.00%"];
  const numberFormats = Array(values.length).fill(formats);
  sheet.getRange(3, 13, values.length, formats.length).setNumberFormats(numberFormats);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run with the script editor, the following result is obtained. The number formats are used by retrieving from your provided sample Spreadsheet.

[image]

#### Note:

- First, I thought that the images can be directly put to the cells using CellImageBuilder. But, in your situation, the data is large. In this case, I noticed that when `IMAGE` formula is used, the process cost can be reduced from that of CellImageBuilder. So in this sample, I used `IMAGE` formula.

#### Reference:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [setNumberFormats(numberFormats)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats)

Comment: @Sander Vanhemel Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply of `Thank you for the reply. When I run I get the following error: "Exception: You do not have permission to call clearContents at sample2(Code:13:9)" How can I fix this?`, in this case, I'm worried that you are using the script as the custom function. In that case, such error occurs. In this case, please directly run the script with the script editor.

Comment: Hello there! Thank you very much! It did work well. This is for sure a good solution and alternative!